# SwiftUI -> Thread 1: Fatal error: No observable object of type MyObject.Type found (EnvironmentObject in sheet)

Tags: ios, swift, observable, fatal-error, swiftui

I'm building an app with SwiftUI. When I was trying to display a sheet (previously Modal), this error message appears:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: No observable object of type BixiStationCombinedListViewModel.Type found.
>
> A View.environmentObject(_:) for BixiStationCombinedListViewModel.Type may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

This error occurs when I'm using a `@State` variable to display a modal that includes a `Map View` using MapKit.

I don't see why and how I should implement a new `Environment Object`.

Is it because the `Station` I select when tapping on the `CardView`  should be stored globally and the info should be passed to the dedicated `View`?

The `View` handling the `@State`:

```
struct CardView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var bixiModel: BixiStationCombinedListViewModel
    @State private var isModalOpen: Bool = false
        
    var station: BixiStationCombinedViewModel
        
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            
                Card()
                
                StationTextInfo(station: station)

        } .onTapGesture {
            self.isModalOpen = true
            print(self.isModalOpen)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$isModalOpen) {
            BixiStationDetailView(station: self.station)
        }

    }
}
```

The `View` I'm trying to show within the sheet:

```
struct BixiStationDetailView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var bixiModel: BixiStationCombinedListViewModel
        
    var station: BixiStationCombinedViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            MapView(coordinate: station.coordinate, name: station.name)        
        }
    }
}
```

Finally the Object:

```
class BixiStationCombinedListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    init() {
        fetchDataFromApi()
    }
    
    @Published var stationsCombinedList = [BixiStationCombinedViewModel]()
    
    var stationsInformationList = [BixiStationInformationViewModel]()
    var stationsDataList = [BixiStationDataViewModel]()
        
    func fetchDataFromApi() {

        }        
    }
}
```

How can I get rid of the error message and display the proper `View`?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You have to pass your environment object to `BixiStationDetailView`, otherwise it won't have anything to bind to its `@EnvironmentObject`.

```swift
.sheet(isPresented: self.$isModalOpen) {
    BixiStationDetailView(station: self.station)
        .environmentObject(self.bixiModel)
}
```

Since you're presenting `BixiStationDetailView` as a sheet, it isn't a subview of your `CardView` and therefore doesn't inherit its `@EnvironmentObject`.

Comment: Thanks it's working perfectly! Previously I added the `@EnvironmentObject` directly in the view and thought it was enough... But it wasn't.

Comment: I got the same error because i was using the `@EnvironmentObject` annotated object inside `init()`.
The environment object is available only after successful initialisation.

Comment: I just ran into this. I assume since the presented sheet is a new hierarchy it doesn't pass along the environment.

Comment: I just encountered this issue with `NavigationLink`. Adding it to parent views wasn't enough, I had to add the modifier to the `destination: ` argument of the nav link. Not very intuitive.

Comment: Note to others: same crash will happen if you have a `View` that's registered as the settings/preferences view in SwiftUI. Same solution, just put it in the `App` view:   `Settings  { UserDetails().environmentObject(Universals) }`