# Why is there a fatal error: No ObservableObject of type *** found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for *** may be missing as an ancestor of this view

Tags: swiftui

PomodoroModel is *** on the question title as it is too long.

Video of error: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qQw3d7ovFCcio3XWZXLIiRmrNohSuO8o/view?usp=sharing)

The debugger says: SwiftUI/EnvironmentObject.swift:90: Fatal error: No ObservableObject of type PomodoroModel found. A View.environmentObject(_:) for PomodoroModel may be missing as an ancestor of this view.

I am not sure why? I assume I have completed the tutorial correctly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pd90OTQiOaA

I have named the Home file PomodoroHome.

My PomodoroHome.swift file's code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PomodoroHome: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var pomodoroModel: PomodoroModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Focus Timer")
                .font(.title2.bold())
        
            GeometryReader{proxy in
                VStack(spacing: 15){
                    // MARK: Timer Ring
                    ZStack{
                        Circle()
                            .fill(.whiteBlack.opacity(0.03))
                            .padding(-40)
                        
                        Circle()
                            .trim(from: 0, to:pomodoroModel.progress)
                            .stroke(.white.opacity(0.03),lineWidth: 80)
                            .padding(-40)
                        
                        // MARK: Shadow
                        Circle()
                            .stroke(Color("whiteBlack"),lineWidth: 5)
                            .blur(radius: 15)
                            .padding(-2)
                        
                        Circle()
                            .fill(Color("blackWhite"))
                        
                        Circle()
                            .trim(from: 0, to: pomodoroModel.progress)
                            .stroke(Color("whiteBlack").opacity(0.7),lineWidth: 10)
                        
                        // MARK: Knob
                        GeometryReader{proxy in
                            let size = proxy.size
                            
                            Circle()
                                .fill(Color("whiteBlack"))
                                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                                .overlay(content: {
                                    Circle()
                                        .fill(.white)
                                        .padding(5)
                                })
                                .frame(width: size.width, height: size.height, alignment: .center)
                            // MARK: Since view is rotated thats why using X
                                .offset(x: size.height / 2)
                                .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: pomodoroModel.progress * 360))
                        }
                        
                        Text(pomodoroModel.timerStringValue)    .font(.system(size: 45, weight: .light))
                            .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                            .animation(.none, value: pomodoroModel.progress)
                    }
                    .padding(60)
                    .frame(height: proxy.size.width)
                    .rotationEffect(.init(degrees: -90))
                    .animation(.easeInOut, value: pomodoroModel.progress)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
                    
                    Button {
                        if pomodoroModel.isStarted{
                            pomodoroModel.stopTimer()
                        }else{
                            pomodoroModel.addNewTimer = true
                        }
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: !pomodoroModel.isStarted ? "timer" : "pause")
                            .font(.largeTitle.bold())
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                            .background{
                                Circle()
                                    .fill(Color("whiteBlack").opacity(0.03))
                            }
                            .shadow(color: Color("whiteBlack").opacity(0.6), radius: 8, x: 0, y: 0)
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            }
        }
        .padding()
        // .background{
        //    Color("whiteBlack")
        // }
        //.preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        .overlay(content: {
            ZStack{
                Color.black
                    .opacity(pomodoroModel.addNewTimer ? 0.25 : 0)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        pomodoroModel.hour = 0
                        pomodoroModel.minutes = 0
                        pomodoroModel.seconds = 0
                        pomodoroModel.addNewTimer = false
                    }
                
                NewTimerView()
                    .frame(maxHeight: .infinity,alignment: .bottom)
                    .offset(y: pomodoroModel.addNewTimer ? 0 : 400)
            }
            .animation(.easeInOut, value: pomodoroModel.addNewTimer)
        })
        .onReceive(Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()) {
            _ in
            if pomodoroModel.isStarted{
                pomodoroModel.updateTimer()
            }
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: New Timer Bottom Sheet
    @ViewBuilder
    func NewTimerView()->some View{
        VStack(spacing: 15){
            Text("Add New Timer")
                .font(.title2.bold())
                .padding(.top,10)
            
            HStack(spacing: 15){
                Text("\(pomodoroModel.hour) hr")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(0.3))
                    .padding(.horizontal,20)
                    .padding(.vertical,12)
                    .background{
                        Capsule()
                            .fill(.whiteBlack.opacity(0.07))
                    }
                    .contextMenu{
                        ContextMenuOptions(maxValue: 12, hint: "hr") { value in
                            pomodoroModel.hour = value
                        }
                    }
                
                Text("\(pomodoroModel.minutes) min")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(0.3))
                    .padding(.horizontal,20)
                    .padding(.vertical,12)
                    .background{
                        Capsule()
                            .fill(.whiteBlack.opacity(0.07))
                    }
                    .contextMenu{
                        ContextMenuOptions(maxValue: 60, hint: "min") { value in
                            pomodoroModel.minutes = value
                        }
                    }
                
                Text("\(pomodoroModel.seconds) sec")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(0.3))
                    .padding(.horizontal,20)
                    .padding(.vertical,12)
                    .background{
                        Capsule()
                            .fill(.whiteBlack.opacity(0.07))
                    }
                    .contextMenu{
                        ContextMenuOptions(maxValue: 60, hint: "sec") { value in
                            pomodoroModel.seconds = value
                        }
                    }
                
            }
            .padding(.top,20)
            
            Button {
                pomodoroModel.startTimer()
            } label: {
                Text("Save")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.semibold)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(height:60)
                    .padding(.horizontal,100)
                    .background{
                        Capsule()
                            .fill(Color("whiteBlack"))
                    }
            }
            .disabled(pomodoroModel.seconds == 0)
            .opacity(pomodoroModel.seconds == 0 ? 0.5 : 1)
            .padding(.top)
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                .fill(Color("blackWhite"))
                .ignoresSafeArea()
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: Reusable Context Menu Options
    @ViewBuilder
    func ContextMenuOptions(maxValue: Int,hint: String,onClick: @escaping (Int)->())->some View{
        ForEach(0...maxValue,id: \.self){value in
            Button("\(value) \(hint)"){
                onClick(value)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct Home_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FocusView()
            .environmentObject(PomodoroModel())
    }
}
```

I assume there is a problem with line 4 but I am not sure how to solve the problem. The fatal error repeats itself later in the file.

The PomodoroModel.swift (under View folder):

```
import SwiftUI

class PomodoroModel: NSObject,ObservableObject {
    
     // MARK: Timer Properties
    @Published var progress: CGFloat = 1
    @Published var timerStringValue: String = "00:00"
    @Published var isStarted: Bool = false
    @Published var addNewTimer: Bool = false
    
    @Published var hour: Int = 0
    @Published var minutes: Int = 0
    @Published var seconds: Int = 0
    
    // MARK: Total Seconds
    @Published var totalSeconds: Int = 0
    @Published var staticTotalSeconds: Int = 0
    
    // MARK: Starting Timer
    func startTimer(){
        withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.25)){isStarted = true}
        // MARK: Setting String Time Value
        timerStringValue = "\(hour == 0 ? "" : "\(hour):")\(minutes >= 10 ? "\(minutes)":"0\(minutes)")\(seconds >= 10 ? "\(seconds)":"0\(seconds)")"
        // MARK: Calculating Total Seconds for Timer Animation
        totalSeconds = (hour * 3600) + (minutes)
    }

    // MARK: Stopping Timer
    func stopTimer(){
        
    }
    
    // MARK: Updating Timer
    func updateTimer(){
        
    }
}
```

The PomodoroTimerApp.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct PomodoroTimerApp: App {
    // MARK: Since we're doing background fetching initialising here
    @StateObject var pomodoroModel: PomodoroModel = .init()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            FocusView()
                .environmentObject(pomodoroModel)
        }
    }
}
```

FocusView.swift (I renamed it from ContentView.swift as that was separate):

```
import SwiftUI

struct FocusView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var pomodoroModel: PomodoroModel
    var body: some View {
        PomodoroHome()
    }
}

struct FocusView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FocusView()
    }
}
// MARK: this is ContentView.swift
```

I thought the variable was initialised in PomodoroTimerApp.swift though? Please help. Anything would be much appreciated.

I have tried rewatching the tutorial video, revising the code, etc.

Comment: Are you get the message on simulator/device or preview?

Comment: I get the actual error message as I build the app. The program executes but results in a crash when I click on a button. The preview crashes as well if I click on the same button.

Comment: Note, there is a limit (10) on the number of Views you can have in another `View`. Use `Group{...}` if need be.

Comment: you need to pass EnvironmentObject to `overlay` explicitly. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582813/swiftui-thread-1-fatal-error-no-observable-object-of-type-myobject-type-fou

Comment: @timbretimbre I added .environmentObject(pomodoroModel) after the line .animation... but it still does not work??

Comment: Apologies but can anyone give an example, I've tried binding it so many times but I'm still unsure why it is not working and gives me a fatal error

.environmentObject(self.pomodoroModel) drags the fatal error pointer to this line

Comment: I have copied your code, replaced the `Color("whiteBlack")` etc... and it compiles and
 run without giving the error you show. Maybe there is some other code that you are not showing
 responsible for the error. On MacOS 14.2, using Xcode 15.1, tested on real ios17 devices (not Previews) and MacCatalyst. It could be different on older systems.

Comment: Note, your `_Previews` seem to be out of whack, especially `Home_Previews`, should
 be `FocusView_Previews`, and you should have a `PomodoroHome_Previews`.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response, I am using Xcode 15 as well but I am building it with the virtual simulator. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qqn0RiZdPofUl9RboCAb6SeOYH6JPmWw/view?usp=share_link

I have uploaded it to a google drive

I have also made the following changes to the code but it still does not work:

.environmentObject(PomodoroModel()) to FocusView_previews

Comment: I'm not familiar with `virtual simulator`, and don't understand what you have in your Google drive.
If you create a new project in Xcode on a "normal" Mac and add your code to it, do you still get the error?
 As I said in my comment, your code compiles and run without giving the error you show.

Comment: Are you getting the error when using `..._Previews` or on real or simulated devices? If in `..._Previews`, show the code you are using for `FocusView_Previews` and `PomodoroHome_Previews`.

Comment: Sorry I can't seem to format it in the comments but the structures are in my original post.

struct PomodoroHome_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FocusView()
            .environmentObject(PomodoroModel())
    }
}

struct FocusView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FocusView()
            .environmentObject(PomodoroModel())
    }
}

Comment: ok, your `PomodoroHome_Previews` should have `PomodoroHome()` not `FocusView()`

Comment: I have changed it but it still gives the fatal error? I have attached a video link so you can have a look at the problem (the seconds, hours, etc. doesn't give a context menu to pop up). I can video the other bits of my code as well.

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mkMvomgxbpTyPosVvVQOOh2JtGrVBuDF/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Whole video of the error and running project:

[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qQw3d7ovFCcio3XWZXLIiRmrNohSuO8o/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The video you show does not show the same code you have in your question.
 You have two `App`, the `PomodoroTimerApp` which is not `@main`
 and then you also have the `Cool_MintApp`, which you are trying to relaunch.
 However, in `Cool_MintApp`, you are using `ContentView` but you don't declare
 `@StateObject var pomodoroModel: PomodoroModel = .init()` in it.
 Get rid of this mess, use one `@main` App.

Comment: Thank you so much! The app works properly now. Many thanks! How can I thank you?

Comment: No worries. Happy coding.